# How is the best way to implement a Temperature Converter

Tags: java, performance, class

I've implemented a Class that convert a temperature in Celsius. My question is what is the best way to implement a temperature converter? This is the solution I've used.

```
public TemperatureConverter(double measurement, String unit) {
    if(unit.equals("F")){
        result = (measurement - 32) * 5 / 9;
    }
    else if(unit.equals("K")){
        result = measurement + KELVIN_TO_CELSIUS;
    }
    else if(unit.equals("R")){
        result = (5 / 4) * measurement;
    }
}
```

Then, the *toCelsius* method.

```
public double toCelsius() {
    return result;
}
```

And the attributes of the class:

```
private final double KELVIN_TO_CELSIUS = 273.15;
private double result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems incomplete:

`100c` (celsius) on your program would be `273.15`, just as `0c` or even `10000c` would still be `273.15`, and this is wrong, also, you are never outputting the new unit of measurement.

First, make a static method (conversions do not need an object), that receives a number, a unit of measurement of the entry value, and a unit of measurment of the output value, and returns a number

```
public static double convertValue(double value, String to){
   if(to.equals("c")){
      return value;
   } else {
      if(to.equals("k")){
         return value + 273.15;
      } else {
         return (value - 32) * 5 / 9;
      }
   }
}
```

To use this, just do `System.out.println(TemperatureConverter.convertValue(50, "k"));` or `System.out.println(TemperatureConverter.convertValue(50, "f"));`

Comment: Just an addition for a learning aspect. The measurement unit could be an enum class with its values. And also be passed as argument instead of `String to`. What do you think?

Comment: @Patrick Seems good, however, since the OP asked a question with only simple mechanics, I tried to remove anything that is not "necessary" to perform the task. The enumeration of possible values would be a right approach, but require knowledge I do not believe that OP has... In my answer, I even removed un-necessary variables....

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new object just for conversion is not the best approach. If your class is doing more than that then their might be some reason for creating the `TemperatureConverter` object.
If conversion is the only thing you require, than you can either create a common static class that can also contain common tasks that your program require or you can create `TemperatureConverter` with static functions for doing the conversion.

You can have individual static functions for each conversions like:

```
double Util.celciusTo(double temp, TempUnit to) 
double Util.fahrenheitTo(double temp, TempUnit to)
double Util.kelvinTo(double temp, TempUnit to)
```

`TempUnit` is the temperature unit enumeration. You can either create the `Util` class and add more utility function or create `TemperatureConverter` containing static functions as above just for temperature conversion.

If your `TemperatureConverter` is doing more than just conversion, like comparing temperature to sort a `List` etc, than you can have such class, but there are few things that you should do:

- Dont do the conversion within the constructor. Do it on demand
- Provide getter functions for current value and unit
- Provide three functions for conversion that will update the internal state of object (update measurement and unit) and return the updated value
- Override toString function for nice printing of values

Comment: I think I can write the static functions inside the static class Util, in this case. In fact I need to convert not only temperature, but also lenght, weight and others.

Comment: Yes, you can create a Util class and use it across your program.